# A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property error in c#

Tags: c#

When I run the windows form application it shows `initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property`.

```
string lia = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
StreamReader fileitem=new StreamReader(Path.Combine(lia,"dataset.txt")); //Error line
```

I thin, it can not recognize `lia` as string.
Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure those two lines follow right after each other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I thin, it can not recognize lia as string.

No, it's recognizing it just fine - but as the error says, you can't use the value of one instance variable within the initializer for another.

The simplest fix is usually to put the initialization in the constructor instead:

```
public class Foo
{
    // TODO: Fix names to be more conventional and friendly
    string lia = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    StreamReader fileitem;

    public Foo()
    {
        fileitem=new StreamReader(Path.Combine(lia,"dataset.txt"));
    }
}
```

On the other hand, it's not clear that these *should* be fields at all... we don't have enough context to be sure, but perhaps you should consider whether these should be *local* variables within a method, instead of instance fields declared in a class?

Comment: Thanks. If i wanna to use "fileitem" later, what should I do @Jon Skeet? since I got " the name fileitem does not  exist in the current context"?

Comment: @user3403967: Well in that case you *would* want it to be a field... but in general having variables which need to be disposed is a bad idea. Could you perhaps read all the content in your constructor, and store that as a string? It's hard to know the best approach without any more context, but really that's going beyond the scope of the question anyway, to some extent. Hopefully my answer has solved your immediate issue. (If you're getting that error message *even when it's a field* then we'll need more context - and you should probably ask a new question, ideally with a short code example.)